# How to implement gaussian filter to downsample a image from 9x9 block into 5x5 of feature vector?

Tags: java, image-processing

90x90 image is divided into 9x9 blocks with 8 chaincode direction and to minimize the feature downsample is required!! how can i downsample the image into 5x5 block using 5x5 gaussian filter. Is there a library function in java to implement gaussian filter.

Comment: I haven't used Java much before but I know you can use OpenCV and it can resize images for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite know what you are going for, but only for resizing the image, you could use `AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x, y);` and then `at.scale(scaleX, scaleY);` but I suppose you actually want to blur the image.
This is actually a quite simple process, I wrote a method for that once.

```
public BufferedImage blur(int range, int angle)
{
    BufferedImage b = new BufferedImage(main_image.getWidth() * 2, main_image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g = b.createGraphics();
    
    for(int x = 0; x < main_image.getWidth(); x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < main_image.getHeight(); y++)
        {
            
            int red[] = new int[range * 2], green[] = new int[range * 2], blue[] = new int[range * 2];
            int pixels[] = new int[range * 2];
            
            for(int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++)
            {
                pixels[i] = main_image.getRGB(clamp(x - clamp(range / 2, 0, range) + i, 0, main_image.getWidth() - 1), clamp(y - clamp(range / 2, 0, range) + (int)(i * Math.toRadians(angle)), 0, main_image.getHeight() - 1));
                
                red[i] = (pixels[i] >> 16) & 0xff;
                green[i] = (pixels[i] >> 8) & 0xff;
                blue[i] = (pixels[i]) & 0xff;
            }
            
            int red_t = 0, green_t = 0, blue_t = 0;
            
            for(int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++)
            {
                red_t += red[i];
                green_t += green[i];
                blue_t += blue[i];
            }
            
            int r = red_t / (range * 2);
            int gr = green_t / (range * 2);
            int bl = blue_t / (range * 2);
            
            //System.out.println(r + ", " + gr + ", " + bl);
            
            g.setColor(new Color(r, gr, bl));
            g.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
            
        }
    }
    g.dispose();
    
    return b;
}
```

This, is actually a pretty simple linear fiter. For a gaussian filter you would have to make the `pixels`, `red`, `green` and `blue` variable into a 2-dimensional array, and just repeat the whole procces for the y axis. If you understand, how the gaussian blue works, you should have no problem implementing this or changing it to a gaussian filter. If you want, you can ask me stuff about it.